# How to reroute all content that ends in `.html` to the root route (by only changing routes.rb)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a bunch of expired content at URLs all ending in `.html` from a legacy static HTML site:

```
example.com/a.html
example.com/b.html
```

Rather than display a Rails error page that says:

```
Routing Error
No route matches "/a.html" with {:method=>:get}
```

I want to reroute all content that ends in `.html` to the homepage (the root route):

```
map.root :controller => 'home', :action => 'index'
```

**Is it possible to do this by only changing the route definition or is it necessary to [define a catch-all route](http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2007/08/23/simple-rails-routes-catch-all-redirect-instead-of-404/)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like the following, in config/routes.rb:

```
map.connect ':pagename.html', :controller => 'home', :action => 'index'
```

See the [Regular Routes section of the Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#regular-routes) for more information on this style of route.